# Matlab: axis command to control spy command's axis labeling for a sparse matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, sparse-matrix, axis-labels

The data has 12 rows and, instead of the N-th row 1...12, the plot should have a column going from 6...89 like the first column of the data. Then the X-coordinate is for the other two rows. The docs about spy mentions nothing about the axis so tried the following but not working

```
>> spy(C(neg,:))
>> axis([1 31 6 89]); spy(C(neg,:))                  #xmin xmax ymin ymax
>> axis on; axis([1 31 6 89]); spy(C(neg,:))
>> axis on; a=spy(C(neg,:)); axis(a,[1 31 6 89]);
Error using spy
Too many output arguments.
```

so

> **How to visualise the sparse data with rightly-labelled axis?**

**Example**

> **Data**
>
> ```
> 6   2   7
> 11  4   7
> 26  9   7
> 36  12  7
> 44  15  7
> 55  21  7
> 60  16  11  7
> 62  23  7
> 86  28  7
> 87  27  7
> 89  25  11  7
> ```
>
> **This plot shows the vertical labels wrongly 0 2 4 ... 12 instead of  6 7 ... 89**
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the expression such as `C([10,20,100],:)` is that it will change your Y-axis so your original 10 will be one, the original 20 will be 2 and the original 100 will be 3 on the y-axis. The trick is not to take things out because Matlab will redefine the axis so create a new variable `CC` where you redefine the unwanted things to zero and then as Masi mentioned use the axis -- after the spy command!

**Example**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's try an example with full matrix

```
sami = sparse(1000,1000);
spy(1 - sami);
axis([1 31 6 89]);
```

You get the left-hand-side picture first and then the right-hand-side

[image]

Your mistake is here: the command **axis on** is reduntant. 
You probably confuse it with the command **hold on**.

Then, you have a typo here in the command

```
axis(a,[1 31 6 89]);
```

which should be only

```
axis([1 31 6 89]);
```

Keep going!